# Best practices to implement "complex" urls in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an enterprise application and would like to use urls with long / non trivial ids instead of the regular, incremental ids.

For instance I'd like to have something like http://mysite.com/users/23lkfjls0934 or http://mysite.com/companies/23lkfjls0934 instead of http://mysite.com/users/3 or http://mysite.com/companies/company-name

What are the steps to follow (migrations, associations, models...) to achieve this result and what is important to keep in mind while building this feature?

Comment: Just curious, what do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, an obvious one is I don't want people to know their user id (=how many users are registered). Also, at some point users will be able to post content, and I'll need a "secret" url for them to share it. More generally, it's a feature that I see in many enterprise apps. It gives companies a feeling of security.

Comment: Using this to hide real user count - fine. Using this to "protect" private resource - absolutely not. It's a typical security by obscurity and it doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't it what Google or Dropbox do with their "Anyone who has the link can view" or "Share link" feature? I understand it's not 100% private and secure, but it's "hard enough" for a random person to find a document, isn't it (Dropbox uses the file name in addition to the 16-character hash to validate the URL)?

Comment: Yes, it's acceptable if you advertise the fact that anyone with the link can access the private resource. Enterprisey software often requires stronger guarantees, like proper access control lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem to do the contrary: make URLs as not-friendly as possible :)

Add a new field to your table, it will store your long key. Then use it like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :long_random_key
end
```

You can initialize this long key in a `before_create` hook, for example.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :long_random_key

  before_create :generate_long_random_key

  private
  def generate_long_random_key
    self.long_random_key = SecureRandom.hex(32)
    # TODO: Make sure it's unique
  end
end
```